# Is there an error in this epsilon-delta proof of the limit law for the sums of functions?

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, epsilon-delta

One of my Calculus profs recorded [a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cd0Gy45H1Qk) (screenshot below) to prove the limit law for the sums of functions:

> $$\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = L \ \wedge \ \lim_{x\to a} g(x) = M \Longrightarrow \lim_{x\to a} (f(x) + g(x)) = L + M$$

But I think he made a small mistake.

I think he should've taken $\delta = \max \{\delta_1, \delta_2\}$ instead of $\min \{ \delta_1, \delta_2\}$.

Is that right, or am I misunderstanding something?

[image: Screenshot of the proof from the video. The small text in green, blue, and orange is my addition.]

(The small text in green, blue, and orange is my addition.)

Comment: Not able to watch the video "Video unavailable
This video is private."

Comment: Yes, the video I linked is no longer available for public viewing. I suspect the professor replaced the video with a new one. He's done that in the past.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, $\min$ is correct. Let's take your example numbers just to have something concrete to work with.

If $0<|x-a|<2$, then clearly $0<|x-a|<3$ also holds. So the hypothesis for (2) holds, and we are good to go.

On the other hand, if we only require $0<|x-a|<3$, then we do not neccessarily have $0<|x-a|<2$, so the hypothesis of (1) doesn't hold, and thus we can't conclude that $|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon/2$.

Basically, given our $\varepsilon$, we have found several $\delta_i$'s, each one restricting what $x$ can be for that specific part of the argument to hold. We pick the most restrictive of all the $\delta_i$ in order to ensure that *all* of the hypotheses hold simultaneously, which again mean that all the conclusions hold, and we can go on to complete our proof.

Comment: I think I was confused about the $\min$ and $\max$ functions. This helped cleared it up, thanks!

To make it even more concrete, I would add to paragraph 3 that if $|x - a| < 3$, it could be that $|x - a| = 2$, which would not satisfy $|x - a| < 2$, and thus $(1)$ would not necessarily be true.

Comment: @Calculemus Or it could be $2.5$. But yeah, that's the gist of it.

Answer (score 5):

It should be $\min$:

We want $|f(x)-L|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$, and this only happens when $|x-a|<\delta_1$. Similarly, we want $|g(x)-L|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$, which only happens when $|x-a|<\delta_2$.

Thus we want $|x-a|$ to be smaller than *both* $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$, that is, $x<\min(\delta_1,\delta_2)$. Thus we set $\delta=\min(\delta_1,\delta_2)$.

If $|x-a|$ were less than only the maximum of $\delta_1,\delta_2$ then it is possible that $\delta_1<x<\delta_2$, so $|f(x)-L|>\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ which is obviously bad for the proof.

I hope this clears things up :)